# why value direction in usmap with ggplot are different for factors and continuous values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I draw two maps with discrete factors (the upper one) and continuous values (the lower one). Why the first one starts from 0 and the second one ends at 0? How can I make them in a more consistent way?

```
map1 <- 
  plot_usmap(data = df[,c(1,7)], 
           regions="states", 
           values="factor",
           labels = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 'GnBu',direction = -1)
map2 <- 
  plot_usmap(data = dfallother[,c(1,8)], 
             regions="states", 
             values="amount",
             labels = TRUE)
```

[image]
I tried with `direction = -1` but it seems not the right way.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`direction` is for the order of the colors, not for labels, you can reverse the labels (or so called breaks) of the legend:

```
library(usmap)
df = statepop
df$factor = factor(sample(0:4,nrow(df),replace=TRUE))
df$amount = runif(nrow(df),min=0,max=5000)

plot_usmap(data = df, 
           regions="states", 
           values="factor",
           labels = TRUE)+
scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 'GnBu',
limits = sort(levels(df$factor),decreasing=TRUE))
```

[image]